# I want to create UITabBar controller + UINavigationBar. I have some problems

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I created tabbar template app. I changed from UIViewController to UINavigationController in the MainWindow.xib. Then I added "next screen" button. When user taps on this button I will push a new view controller. But how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To push to next ViewController

[self.navigationController pushViewController:nameOfYourViewController animated:YES];

Comment: This will make the navigation controller push a new view. Make sure you have your Tabbar on the level above the navigation controller, else you will lose the tab bar.